# primeng listbox con grupos y menú contextual

Tags: angular, primeng

Me encontré [este código](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-project-angular-11-trn3zr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) para ponerle un menu contextual (p-contextMenu) a una lista (p-listbox)

Pero ahora quiero hacer lo mismo con una lista que haga agrupación como la que viene en [su documentación](https://primeng.org/listbox#group).

Esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora.

HTML

```
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
    <p-listbox [options]="groupedCities" [group]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" [listStyle]="{ 'max-height': '250px' }" [style]="{ width: '15rem' }">
        <ng-template let-group pTemplate="group">
            <div class="flex align-items-center">
                <img src="https://primefaces.org/cdn/primeng/images/demo/flag/flag_placeholder.png" [class]="'mr-2 flag flag-' + group.value" style="width: 20px" />
                <span (contextmenu)="showMenu(menu, $event, group)">{{ group.label }}</span>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-listbox>
</div>
<p-contextMenu [model]="items" [global]="true"></p-contextMenu>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectItemGroup } from 'primeng/api';

interface Country {
    name: string,
    code: string
}

@Component({
    selector: 'listbox-group-demo',
    templateUrl: './listbox-group-demo.html'
})
export class ListboxGroupDemo {
    groupedCities!: SelectItemGroup[];

    selectedCountry!: Country;

    items: MenuItem[] | undefined;

    constructor() {
        this.groupedCities = [
            {
                label: 'Germany',
                value: 'de',
                items: [
                    { label: 'Berlin', value: 'Berlin' },
                    { label: 'Frankfurt', value: 'Frankfurt' },
                    { label: 'Hamburg', value: 'Hamburg' },
                    { label: 'Munich', value: 'Munich' }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'USA',
                value: 'us',
                items: [
                    { label: 'Chicago', value: 'Chicago' },
                    { label: 'Los Angeles', value: 'Los Angeles' },
                    { label: 'New York', value: 'New York' },
                    { label: 'San Francisco', value: 'San Francisco' }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'Japan',
                value: 'jp',
                items: [
                    { label: 'Kyoto', value: 'Kyoto' },
                    { label: 'Osaka', value: 'Osaka' },
                    { label: 'Tokyo', value: 'Tokyo' },
                    { label: 'Yokohama', value: 'Yokohama' }
                ]
            }
        ];

        this.items = [
        {
            label: 'File',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
            items: [
                {
                    label: 'New',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus',
                    items: [
                        {
                            label: 'Bookmark',
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bookmark'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Video',
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-video'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    label: 'Delete',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash'
                },
                {
                    separator: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Export',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-external-link'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Edit',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
            items: [
                {
                    label: 'Left',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-left'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Right',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-right'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Center',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-center'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Justify',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-justify'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Users',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user',
            items: [
                {
                    label: 'New',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user-plus'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Delete',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user-minus'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Search',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-users',
                    items: [
                        {
                            label: 'Filter',
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-filter',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    label: 'Print',
                                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-print'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bars',
                            label: 'List'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Events',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar',
            items: [
                {
                    label: 'Edit',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
                    items: [
                        {
                            label: 'Save',
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar-plus'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Delete',
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar-minus'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    label: 'Archieve',
                    icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar-times',
                    items: [
                        {
                            label: 'Remove',
                            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar-minus'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            separator: true
        },
        {
            label: 'Quit',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-power-off'
        }
    ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Que tal, ¿Has tenido algún error hasta el momento?

Comment: No da error, solamente que se activa en el nivel superior de grupo, pero no en el interior